# $interval inside of a for loop

Tags: angularjs, setinterval, angular-promise

I'm looking for a way to count down from 3 and save a picture from a video element a series of 4 times. So countDownTimer would be 3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1. See code below. Right now the code sets countDownTimer to "3", 4 times in a row and then counts down to -9.  I think I understand why this is happening but is there a way to get the timer to reset to 3 to get the desired output?

```
    //Counts down from 3 before each picture and adds each picture to the canvas
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        $scope.countDownTimer = 3  //reset timer to 3
        console.log($scope.countDownTimer);

      //counts down from 3
      $interval(function(){
        $scope.countDownTimer = $scope.countDownTimer - 1;
        console.log($scope.countDownTimer);
      }, 1000, 3)
      //takes picture and adds to canvas
      .then(function(){
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, dx[i], dy[i], picWidth, picHeight);
      })
    }
```

Comment: what's the `for` loop for? Will create 4 interval timers running simultaneously

Comment: I guess what I want to do is wait to start the next iteration again until the $interval function completes.  I wasn't thinking about it starting 4 timers simultaneously but that does make sense!

Comment: So would I be better off just chaining 4 $setinterval functions together?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about printing the countdown you may can try something like this.

```
     //Counts down from 3 before each picture and adds each picture to the canvas
            for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
                your code..

              //counts down from 3
              $interval(function(){
//takes picture and adds to canvas
              .then(function(){
                canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, dx[i], dy[i], picWidth, picHeight);
              })

              }, 3000, 3)
            }
```

Comment: I was hoping to print the countdown on the screen.